# How to prove $\ln x<x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logarithms

How can we prove that the inequality 
$$\ln~x<x$$

It is trivial in the cases $0<x\le 1$. I couldn't do anything for $x>1$.

Comment: What is the definition of the logarithm you're working with?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is natural logarithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: Consider the related inequality $0<x-\ln x$.

Comment: Yes, but we can define it in different ways. As the inverse of the exponential function, as $\int_1^x \frac{dx}{x}$, …

Comment: @DanielFischer it is the inverse of exponential function.

Comment: Okay, so translate the inequality into $t < e^t$. Depending on the used definition of the exponential function, the inequality may be obvious, or not quite.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger could you write more explict?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that a function is increasing?

Answer (score 10):

This is one way to see it among others.

The function $x\mapsto\ln(1+x)$ is a concave function (it's twice differentiable and its second derivative is strictly negative). Thus it's below all its tangents.

The tangent at the point $(0,0)$ is the line $y=x$. Hence
$$\forall x>0,\, \ln(1+x)\leq x$$

We deduce from this that
$$\forall x>0,\, \ln x<x$$

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to make use of the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}<1$ for $x>1$. Thus, $\ln(x)$ increases slower than $x$ when $x>1$.

For $x>1$ we have

$$\ln(x)=\int_{1}^x \frac{1}{\tau} d\tau$$
$$x=1+\int_{1}^x 1 d\tau $$

thus

$$\ln(x)-x=\underbrace{\int_{1}^x \left(\frac{1}{\tau}-1 \right) d\tau}_{<0\text{ because integrand }<0}-1 < 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Your inequality is equivalent to $x < e^x$ for any $x$. (Substitute $x = \log t$.) It is obvious for $x\le 0$. Moreover, if $x>0$ then the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ gives
$$x < 1+x \le 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots  = e^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is true at $x=1$ and it holds between the derivatives for $x>1$ (and the inverse inequality holds between the derivatives for $0<x<1,$ so that gives another proof for that interval).

Answer (score 0):

This is the graphical representation of your inequality-

[image]

> $$x-\ln(x)=\int 1\space dx-\int \frac{1}{x}\space dx>0$$

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, I think.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yeah...I have seen that you have mentioned my point in a comment but,I see that OP is unable to understand it and asks you for a more explicit explanation...so,I thought this might help (if I could add images in comment I would have done so):-)...

Comment: Convert it into an answer by noting that $x-\ln x$ is infinitely differentiable and that it has a unique local extremum, where the second derivative happens to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}x$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\frac{(x-1)e^x}{x^2}$$
So $x=1$ is the turning point. And obviously, $\forall x>1$, $f'(x)>0$. So $f(x)$ is increasing in $(1,\infty)$.

Meanwhile, $\forall x\in(0,1)$, $f'(x)<0$ and  $f(x)$ is decreasing.

So equivalently, we say $\forall x , f(x)>f(1)=e>1$.

Here

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x}>1\iff e^x>x \iff x>\ln x$$

Answer (score 0):

If you start with $e^x > 1 + x$ and apply the logarithmic function, which is increasing, to both sides then you get $\log(x + 1) < x \implies \log(u) < u -1$. This gives you even a tighter bound.

Answer (score -3):

[image]
Well, graphically, you can easily prove that. Plotting $\color {blue}{y = e^x}$ vs $\color{red}{y = x}$ graph, we can see:

$e^x > x$

Take log on both sides (Considering only +ve values of $x$).

$x > \ln x$

Comment: I have edited to add colors to your answer to make it more attractive and colorful!!:-)

Comment: Alright @tatan :)